# On-the-fly zipping using Ionic.Zip c#

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying to create a zip file from a stream and in return a stream, my problem is I don't want to store any data in my local hard disk or in memory. I am using `Ionic.Zip` Library

```
        Stream output = new MemoryStream();
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            Stream s = ftpManager.GetFileStream("/mydoc.docx");
            ZipEntry e = zip.AddEntry("Content-From-Stream.bin", s);
            e.Comment = "The content for entry in the zip file was obtained from a stream";
            //zip.AddFile("Readme.txt");
            zip.Save(output);
        }
        if (output != null)
        {
            ftpManager.Upload(output, "/MohamedTest/mydoc.zip");
        }
```

There are many problems in that code,

- First, I am using MemoryStream which is not preferable
- Second, zipped file is empty after compress

any suggestions

Comment: I am curious, why the downvote? It seems a legitimate question with a well exposed problem

Comment: Your memory/disk space problem cannot be simply resolved. In order to upload a file to ftp you need to know it's size (using FtpWebRequest, content size needs to be set before uploading file). ZIP file size will only be known after archive has been fully compressed. The only choice you have got is between memory and disk space usage.

Comment: @KamilKrasinski I think I can get file size from stream because, I already stream the zipped file, But the problem is the storing of that stream in memory because of large files. I want to avoid such a thing

Comment: @MohamedSalah That's why I'm saying you don't know size of the zip file early enough to start uploading it to ftp in chunks before all of it is compressed. If you are worried about memory you're only option is to zip file to disk and read chunk by chunk and upload to ftp (using byte[] buffer reads on the stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely position on output is set to the end of stream after compression, please check this.
And, unless you will implement some proxyfying stream (which will handle .Write method and send this data to FTP) you need memory/file stream to store the zipped data.

Comment: Thanks @Nickolay that solves upload problem i set position of stream to 0 after zip completes and that works fine
But I am still have the problem of using memory stream

Comment: Actually, why using MemoryStream is a problem?

Comment: using MemoryStream is a problem because i use the memory to store data on it instead of storing data on disk and that is a big problem because if user have a large file say 2 Giga i have to put that file into memory and wait till that file downloaded as a stream in memory then complete my logic imagine if there are 2 or 3 users what size of memory i need